# how to ssh to my remote docker containers using nginx reverse proxy

Tags: php, linux, docker, ssh, nginx-reverse-proxy

My architecture is as follows:

1. I have Linux server with IP addr. 192.168.10.1 running nginx, and nginx can only listen on port 80.
2. I have another server with IP addr. 192.168.10.2 running my Docker containers that have already OpenSSH installed on them and published with different ports each one of them; ex. container1 published with port 2222:22.

Now my problem is that I want to ssh (from internet) to my container1 for example mentioned previously, but I have to pass throw nginx reverse proxy  that listens only on port 80.
Any idea will be helpful, thank you all.

Comment: You can't really proxy ssh (a binary TCP-based protocol) over HTTP.  Why is making an ssh connection into your containers so important, and why this specific architecture?

Comment: first this architecture is imposed, and i am trying to develop web site that provide linux terminal for students to practise linux commands  so each student access the web site a container is created (ex ubuntu container) and then i want to display the terminal of that container on the page of my web site so the student can practise linux cmds as i said if there is another suggestion other than ssh to access these containers i am happy to hear thnks

Answer (score 0):

this is not possible -> you can open ssh on your first host though

Not only because neither apache nor nginx can tunnel ssh connections, but also because a docker container should not run more than one application - to ssh into one you would have to run sshd next to the application within your container as well